# How to install Ubuntu Desktop on Windows Vista

Tags: system-installation

I have copied Ubuntu Desktop to a blank DVD.
However, when I boot my PC with Windows Vista, it doesn't prompt me to install Ubuntu.

Where are my getting all wrong?

Comment: You need to boot the computer from the DVD rather than from the hard disk